# ConnectionFactory get destroyed before camel

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I'm using spring-boot with camel and ActiveMQ.

I'm using activemq autoconfiguration via @EnableJms annotation.
But creating my own ActiveMQComponent to enable "transacted(true)" on all queues.

```
@Bean(name = "activemq")
@ConditionalOnClass(ActiveMQComponent.class)
public ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    ActiveMQComponent activeMQComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMQComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    activeMQComponent.setTransacted(true);
    activeMQComponent.setTransactionManager(jmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory));
    return activeMQComponent;
}
```

It works well but when I try to gracefully shutdown the application.
The PooledConnectionFactory get destroyed before the camel graceful shutdown happens.

Leading to a tons of error and the route unable to correctly stops.

Like 20 times this error :

```
2017-05-04 18:21:59.748  WARN 12188 --- [er[test.queue]] o.a.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession      : Caught exception trying rollback() when putting session back into the pool, will invalidate. javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
```

Followed by:

```
2017-05-04 18:21:59.748  INFO 12188 --- [      Thread-18] o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext      : Apache Camel 2.18.3 (CamelContext: route) is shutting down
```

Then later :

`2017-05-04 18:21:59.766  INFO 12188 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Waiting as there are still 1 inflight and pending exchanges to complete, timeout in 300 seconds. Inflights per route: [test2 = 1]`

Anyone can help me configuring spring-boot camel activemq all together with graceful shutdown ?

Thanks

**Update :**
Here is a sample of my pom.xml:

```
        <properties>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-boot.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>

        <!-- Camel -->
        <camel-spring-boot.version>2.18.3</camel-spring-boot.version>
    </properties>
    ....

    <!-- Camel BOM -->
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${camel-spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- ActiveMQ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Update 2:**
After further investigation and the creation of a new project adding every modification one by one I have isolated the problem.

The shutdown works correcly until I add a specific endpoint :

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "direct:aaa")
private Endpoint errorHandling;
```

Using :

```
private String errorHandling = "direct:aaa";
```

Doesn't produce the bug.

It seems like using @EndpointInject is making the activemq close first

**Update 3 :**

Found that SpringCamelContext is not implementing ApplicationListener and thus its method "onApplicationEvent" its not called handling the "shutdownEager" of camel.

Comment: method SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent is called with ContextStoppedEvent , turn your logs to trace or DEBUG

Comment: Added breakpoint, its never called. Created a component listening for this event, then manually calling springCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(event). And it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Important thing is to use Camel Spring Boot Starter.

http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html

How to enable Camel auto-configuration in my Spring Boot application?

Just drop camel-spring-boot jar into your classpath:

> ```
>  <dependency>
>      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
>      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
>      <version>${camel.version}</version> <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
> </dependency>
> ```

camel-spring-boot jar comes with the spring.factories file, so as soon as you add that dependency into your classpath, Spring Boot will automatically auto-configure the Camel for you. Yay! That was fast ;) .

Auto-configured Camel context

The most important piece of functionality provided by the Camel auto-configuration is the CamelContext instance.

***Camel auto-configuration creates SpringCamelContext for your and take care of the proper initialization and shutdown of that context.***

Created Camel context is also registered in the Spring application context (under camelContext bean name), so you can access it just as the any other Spring bean.

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {

  @Autowired
  CamelContext camelContext;

  @Bean
  MyService myService() {
    return new DefaultMyService(camelContext);
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated my question with a sample of my pom.xml. I'm using camel-spring-boot and everything is auto configured. The problem is really the activemq being destroyed before camel routes.

Comment: add another beans definitions like connectionFactories, broker, camel

Comment: Updated my question, it is related to @EndpointInject don't know how/why

Comment: try to use `@Produce(uri = "direct:aaa")`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently since https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-2607 
the SpringCamelContext doesn't implement ApplicationListener interface anymore.

Since I'm using spring-boot autoconfiguration, I am not using CamelContextFactoryBean which is adding the listener.

Has a temporary fix, I created a component which listen to ApplicationEvent and dispatch them to the SpringCamelContext method :

```
public class SpringCamelContextFix implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

private SpringCamelContext camelContext;

public SpringCamelContextFix(SpringCamelContext camelContext) {
    this.camelContext = camelContext;
}

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
    camelContext.onApplicationEvent(event);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem running unit/integration tests with Spring Boot, ActiveMQ or A-MQ, and Camel (version 2.18.1.redhat-000012). Apparently, when Spring Boot shuts down, the JMS thread pool is closed before the Camel context is shutdown, which is the wrong order. @John D provided a code fix in a [Camel users mailing list thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/OnApplicationEvent-not-called-with-CamelAutoConfiguration-td5798802.html) which is similar to what he provided in this thread.  Here is the version of John D's code that worked for me:

```
@Component 
public class SpringCamelContextFix implements 
ApplicationListener<ApplicationEvent> {

    @Inject
    private SpringCamelContext camelContext;

    public SpringCamelContextFix(SpringCamelContext camelContext) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        camelContext.onApplicationEvent(event);
    }
}
```